# React Native - Warning: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native, react-native-navigation

> Warning: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)
>
> TypeError: Object is not a function (evaluating 'concreteComponentProvider()')

This is the Warning I get after adding React Redux in my App. It might some conflict about the React Redux and React Native Navigation (latest version) or also the React Native Vector Icons.

I think what causing the Error is in this code, the `startMainTabs.js`. This is where I code all my React Native Navigation.

Feel free to ask for more of my codes or any questions. Thank you!

These are my codes:
App.js

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

//Register Screens
Navigation.registerComponent("Event.AuthScreen", () => AuthScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent("Event.Map", () => EventMap);
Navigation.registerComponent("EventCreator", () => EventCreator, store, Provider);
Navigation.registerComponent("EventHome", () => EventHome, store, Provider);

Navigation.setRoot({
root: {
stack: {
  children: [{
    component: {
      name: "Event.AuthScreen",
    }
  }],
  options: {
    topBar: {
      title: {
        text: 'Welcome'
      }
    }
  }
}
}
});
```

startMainTabs.js

```
const startTabs = () => {
Promise.all([
Icon.getImageSource("ios-home", 30),
 Icon.getImageSource("ios-map", 30),
 Icon.getImageSource("ios-share-alt", 30)
]).then(sources => {
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [{
        stack: {
          children: [{
            component: {
              name: "Event.Map",
            }
          }],
          options: {
            bottomTab: {
              icon: sources[1],
              testID: 'FIRST_TAB_BAR_BUTTON'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        stack: {
          children: [{
            component: {
              name: "EventHome"
            }
          }],
          options: {
            bottomTab: {
              icon: sources[0],
              testID: 'SECOND_TAB_BAR_BUTTON'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        component: {
          name: "EventCreator",
          options: {
            bottomTab: {
              icon: sources[2],
              testID: 'THIRD_TAB_BAR_BUTTON'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  }
});
})
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful. I tried to remove the 2 screens where I added the Redux. I tried to run, press the "login" button to navigate in startTabBasedApps and its working. Maybe the problem is registering the screens with Redux is different in RNNv2.

Answer (score 0):

in newest version of react native navigation from wix you should use 
`registerComponentWithRedux` instead of `registerComponent`,
and set Provider before store

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("Event.AuthScreen", () => AuthScreen,Provider,store);
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("Event.Map", () => EventMap,Provider,store);
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("EventCreator", () => EventCreator,Provider,store);
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("EventHome", () => EventHome,Provider,store);
```

In the newest version of the RNN you should use `registerComponentWithRedux` instead of `registerComponent` and the `Provider` comes first then `store`, like the above code example